# unable to call jquery after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

In my xhtml page, first time page looks ok but when I click on h:commandLink which sends ajax request
when it reload the page css and jquery not loading. so color and table view changed.
my table is :

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" class="role_detail_section">
        <thead><tr>
            <th>Relationship-Type Name</th>

            <c:forEach items="#{manageRelationBean.languageList}" var="languageName" >
                <th>#{languageName}</th>
            </c:forEach>
            <th>Edit | Deactivate</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="#{manageRelationBean.languageRelList}" var="languageRelDTO">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    #{languageRelDTO.relationName}
                </td>
                <c:forEach items="#{languageRelDTO.languageList}" var="relationValues">
                    <td>#{relationValues.relationValue}</td>
                </c:forEach>
                <td>
                <span><h:commandLink value="Edit" class="edit_icon" action="#{relationBean.editRelationByRelationType}" immediate="true" >
             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{relationBean.relationType}" value="#{languageRelDTO.relationName}" />
             </h:commandLink></span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                <span><p:commandLink  rendered="#{manageRelationBean.findRelationStatus(languageRelDTO.country.countryCode,languageRelDTO.relationName) eq 1}" value=" Activate " action="#{manageRelationBean.activateRelation(languageRelDTO.relationName)}" update="@form" process="@this" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{relationBean.relationType}" value="#{languageRelDTO.relationName}" />
             </p:commandLink>   
    <p:commandLink rendered="#{manageRelationBean.findRelationStatus(languageRelDTO.country.countryCode,languageRelDTO.relationName) eq 3}" value=" Deativate " action="#{manageRelationBean.softDeactivateRelation(languageRelDTO.relationName)}" update="@form" process="@this">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{relationBean.relationType}" value="#{languageRelDTO.relationName}" />
             </p:commandLink>
    </span>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach></tbody>
    </table>
```

and jquery for table colouring is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".role_detail_section tr:odd").addClass("activity_white");
$(".role_detail_section tr:even").addClass("activity_blue");    
});
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML and the code of the AJAX call. My guess is that you need to delegate some events somewhere.

Comment: [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp2nq/)

Answer (score 1):

use [delegate() or on()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in order to bind handler to an element that is regenerated on runtime.

The delegate : `Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding one attribute in jsf commandLink thats onComplete

```
onComplete="addCSS()"
```

and function written

```
function addCSS(){
$(".role_detail_section tr:odd").addClass("activity_white");
$(".role_detail_section tr:even").addClass("activity_blue");
}
```